# How do I make this function update the current mouse position?

Tags: javascript, location

I'm making a drawing pad, and I want the mouse location to update in an array as the mouse is dragged. Here is my code:

```
function penDown (x, y) {
  isPenDown = true;
  localPen.x = x;
  localPen.y = y;
}

var X = [],
Y = [],
i = -1;

function penMove (x, y) {
  if (isPenDown) {
     ++i; 
     X[i] = localPen.x;
     Y[i] = localPen.y;
     console.log("i is " + i + ", x is " + X[i] + ", y is " + Y[i]);
 }
};
```

The console log shows that i is updating continuously when you move the mouse, but the X and Y coordinates of the mouse don't change - they just stay on the initial mouse location when you first press down the mouse.

Here is how I call penDown:

```
function pointerDownListener (e) {
  // Retrieve a reference to the Event object for this mousedown event.
  var event = e || window.event; 
  // Determine where the user clicked the mouse.
  var mouseX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

  // Move the drawing pen to the position that was clicked
  penDown(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function pointerMoveListener (e) {

  var event = e || window.event; // IE uses window.event, not e
  var mouseX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

  // Draw a line if the pen is down
  penMove(mouseX, mouseY);

}
```

Comment: can you show how you call `penDown`?

Comment: I take it you are calling the `pointerMoveListener` from a `mousemove` event?

Comment: yep, document.onmousemove = pointerMoveListener;

Comment: I would debug `pointerMoveListener` using developer tools in your browser, check what the values for `event.clientX` and Y, along with `canvas.offsetLeft`

Answer (score 0):

It might be, because your function penDown is only called once, so the values of x and y assigned to localPen won't change.

Comment: I just added some more code, which probably explains what you're saying.